# Unable to fetch Object id of post in android using mongoDb NodeJs as a backend

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb

I am making an android app where I am using MongoDB and NodeJs as a backend service.I have some posts saved on MongoDb and I am retrieving them in recycler view.I have a button in recycler view when it is clicked I want to fetch an Object Id of an item.

I am successfully fetching all documents in recycler view but the problem is 
when I clicked on button in particular item.They are showing Object Id of a document which is inserted recently and not showing correct Object Id of an item.

This is what I have done so far:

**MyPostBookAdapter.java**

```
public class MyPostedBookAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyPostedBookAdapter.ViewHolder> {

List<PostedModel> listItem;
Activity context;
String id;

public MyPostedBookAdapter(List<PostedModel> listItem, Activity context){

    this.listItem = listItem;
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyPostedBookAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.posted_book,viewGroup,false);


    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyPostedBookAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {

    final PostedModel model =  listItem.get(i);

    //Object Id of post
    id = model.getPostId();

    viewHolder.userBookName.setText(model.getPurchaseBookName());

    RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
    requestOptions.placeholder(R.drawable.openbook);

    Glide.with(context).load(model.getPurchaseImage()).apply(requestOptions).into(viewHolder.userPostBook);

    viewHolder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(context,id,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listItem.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView userPostBook;
    TextView userBookName;
    Button delete;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        userPostBook = (itemView).findViewById(R.id.userPostBook);
        userBookName = (itemView).findViewById(R.id.userBookName);
        delete = (itemView).findViewById(R.id.delete);
    }
  }
 }
```

**PostedModel.java**

```
public class PostedModel {

String purchaseImage,purchaseBookName,postId;

public PostedModel(){

}

public PostedModel(String purchaseImage, String purchaseBookName,String postId){

    this.purchaseBookName = purchaseBookName;
    this.purchaseImage = purchaseImage;
    this.postId = postId;
}

public String getPurchaseImage() {
    return purchaseImage;
}

public void setPurchaseImage(String purchaseImage) {
    this.purchaseImage = purchaseImage;
}

public String getPurchaseBookName() {
    return purchaseBookName;
}

public void setPurchaseBookName(String purchaseBookName) {
    this.purchaseBookName = purchaseBookName;
}

public String getPostId() {
    return postId;
}

public void setPostId(String postId) {
    this.postId = postId;
 }
}
```

Please let me know how can I get ObjectId correspond to right item. 
Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Issue is,

Recycler view load every object given one by one, so variable id had the value of last object. So you need to take id from the selected view.

The Fix is,

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyPostedBookAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {

final PostedModel model =  listItem.get(i);

//Object Id of post
id = model.getPostId();

// You need to set this id to viewHolder.
viewHolder.userBookName.setId(id);

viewHolder.userBookName.setText(model.getPurchaseBookName());

RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
requestOptions.placeholder(R.drawable.openbook);

Glide.with(context).load(model.getPurchaseImage()).apply(requestOptions).into(viewHolder.userPostBook);

viewHolder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        //Here you can extract the id which we set at binding
        int idOfView = v.userBookName.getId();

        Toast.makeText(context,idOfView,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      }
});
```

}

Hope this will help you.